# How to send newly created cookies to browser using NodeJS Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, es6-promise

**Overview:**

A user is already logged in so have the required auth cookies set in browser for that user.

I have an endpoint which generates new auth cookies for a different user. I want to send these new cookies to the browser so I am logged in as this new user.

**The problem:**

My endpoint generates the new cookies correctly. But I am not sure how to send these new cookies to the browser so I get logged in as the new user.

**The code:**

This snippet calls the endpoint, which generates new cookies for a given user.

When console logging the response.headers cookies, I can see the new cookies, which I want to send to browser.

```
app.get(['my-api-path'], (req, res) => {
  res.send({userId: req.params.userId, modifiedBy: req.params.modifiedBy});
  axios({url: my-endpoint,
    method: req.method,
    type: 'json',
    headers: { my-headers },
  })
  .then((response) => {
    let setcookie = response.headers["set-cookie"];
    let host = req.headers.host;
    console.log(setcookie);
  })
  .catch((response) => {
    // TO DO add error checks here 
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `res.send({cookie: setcookie})` ?

Comment: I did, but get this error 'Can't set headers after they are sent'

Comment: Is this handler complete or is there something more to it?

Comment: forgot to show that im already calling res.send so i think thats why im getting cant set headers issue. snipped updated above.

Comment: @user3554072 That happens when you send data before or after setting the cookie. Try hitting that cookie URI and then redirect. Once the browser gets the redirect it will ask the server in a get request. ie. Send a request just for the cookie and send data using a different uri.

Comment: You should move your res.send part inside successCallback of axios, `res.send({userId: req.params.userId, modifiedBy: req.params.modifiedBy, cookie: setcookie});`, and if you want to send response even in case of error, you can put same in errorCallback without cookie part

Comment: Also I am curious why you are re-sending same data you received from client in the first place?

Comment: re-sending same data was my bad. was meant to remove this (used for testing).

Comment: its working now. thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use res.cookie before doing sending your response.

```
app.get(['my-api-path'], (req, res) => {
  axios({url: my-endpoint,
    method: req.method,
    type: 'json',
    headers: { my-headers },
  })
  .then((response) => {
     res.cookie("cookieName","cookieValue",{maxAge:3600});
     res.send({userId: req.params.userId, modifiedBy: req.params.modifiedBy});
  })
  .catch((response) => {
    // TO DO add error checks here 
  });
});
```

`res.cookie()` needs to be before the `res.send()`

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie for more information

Answer (score 0):

As my response had multiple cookies in an array, it was better for me to use

```
res.set('Set-Cookie', setcookie);
```

So my final snippet of code looked like this:

```
app.get(['my-api-path'], (req, res) => {
  axios({url: my-endpoint,
    method: req.method,
    type: 'json',
    headers: { my-headers },
  })
  .then((response) => {
    const setcookie = response.headers['set-cookie'];
    res.set('Set-Cookie', setcookie);
    res.send({ userId: req.params.userId, modifiedBy: req.params.modifiedBy});
    next();
  })
  .catch((response) => {
    // TO DO add error checks here 
  });
});
```